# Broken BIOS There's no menu

Tags: windows-10, bios

Im struggling with this problem; When I hit F8 and try to enter in the BIOS menu this **black screen shows up** [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy9YJ.jpg) and I can't do anything. How can I fix it? :(

Disclaimer: I'm trying to enter on BIOS to start on Safe Mode because I messed up something with Windows Permissions, So a solution that *requires to change something from Windows will not help me* :(

I need to flash/reinstall BIOS?
I really don't remember when I started having this problem :/

Comment: You have provided exceedingly little information. Go to the PC Manufacturer's support site and ask for a BIOS download to make a USB Key. Boot from the BIOS USB Key and update the BIOS.  If the BIOS has been bricked (damaged) this will not work, but then nothing else will work except to replace the computer.

Comment: Could be a display or resolution issue. BIOS/UEFI usually shows only on the main display, at *low* resolution. External monitors might not work at all, or only those able to display *low* resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Flashing BIOS would be a good start.

However you should be able to enter Safe Mode from the Windows Recovery Environment. Instead of pressing F8 you can access the WinRE by pressing F11 when your computer boots. When you get to the screen that says "Choose an Option" navigate to Troubleshoot>Advanced Options>Startup Settings.

You'll be presented with a list of options to choose from. Safe Mode options are 4 through 6.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, I tried with F11 but I'm receiveing the same broken black screen either trying to get into BIOS menu either to WRE. You have any idea of what this would be a symptom?

Comment: Is this a laptop or a desktop computer?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for taking so long to answer, it's a desktop computer. I noticed that the first time in the day I boot it **I can access to BIOS** , Is this a thing? I tried replacing the battery. I couldn't flash the BIOS (don't know why) I tried downloading the files to a empty USB and make it bootable with rufus and selected as first boot device but nothing happens!

Comment: Is BIOS functioning now or are you still getting a black screen with no GUI?

Comment: No, I cannot access now I'm getting the black screen with no GUI. I'll try tomorrow when I turn on my PC in the morning. I don't know why it works like this, but today; on the first boot of the day I was able to get into the boot order menu -I wasn't able to achieve this before as getting into BIOS and today on the first boot I colud- (So, sorry I was wrong in the last comment; **I don't know for sure If I can access to BIOS in this way** but as the boot menu worked I think the BIOS might work to). 

Also I didn't mention maybe it's obvious but ** I can access to CMOS at startup**

Comment: Try re-seating the RAM